# PHP script to update mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

another day another question...

I need to write PHP script to update mySQL database.

For example: updating profile page when user want to change their first name, last name or etc.

**Here is my php script so far, it doesn't work. Please help!**

```
<?php
@ $db = new MySQLi('localhost','root','','myDB');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 

$First_Name2 = $_POST['First_Name2'];

$query  = "UPDATE people SET $First_Name2 = First_Name WHERE `Id` = '$id'";

$result = $db->query($query);

if(! $result)
{
    die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";

$db->close();
}
?>
```

THank you.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" look like?  Please provide more info so someone can help you.  Messages would be helpful.  I'm betting that the column name is First_Name, not $First_Name2.  You can't bind column names.

Comment: not really sure what you're asking. can you provide some things that you've tried?

Comment: If only there were prior art on interfacing PHP with MySQL... In any case, what is the actual problem you're having? At what point doesn't it work? Have you tried copying an example you know works, and then gradually changing it until it doesn't?

Comment: The answer is working perfectly. Thank you all for responding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sql is wrong. Apart from the gaping wide open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, you're generating bad sql.

e.g. consider submitting "Fred" as the first name:

```
$First_Name2 = "Fred";
$query = "UPDATE people SET Fred = First_name WHERE ....";
```

now you're telling the db to update a field name "Fred" to the value in the "First_Name" field. Your values must be quoted, and reversed:

```
$query = "UPDATE people SET First_name = '$First_Name2' ...";
```

You are also mixing the mysqli and mysql DB libraries like a drunk staggering down the street. PHP's db libraries and function/method calls are **NOT** interchangeable like that.

In short, this code is pure cargo-cult programming.

Comment: I'm new to php. I heard about this SQL injection. Could you give an example on how to avoid it please ???

Comment: Please show me the way to do it properly... ?? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1