# Profile page doesn't update after update in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have this problem, it should be easy to solve. But i'm new to PHP so please help.

The problem is :

**Profile page doesn't update after update in mySQL database**

For example : 
1. User edit their profile (e.g. First Name) 
2. Click on update.
3. PHP script to update mySQL runs perfectly.
4. First Name in mySQL updated to the new input.
5. The page redirects to profile page.
6. **Problem=** The first name is the **previous first name.**

Users need to log out and sign in again to see their new updated first name.

Here is the code to view the first name in the profile page:

```
echo '<h1>' . $_SESSION['fname'] . '';
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: When you update in the database are you also resetting the session variable?

Comment: Jay Blanchard is correct, unless you have a serialized user object, in that case, you need to refresh and re-serialize.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes, I need to reset the session. The answer accepted is working good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that,you are not reseting $_SESSION['fname']. You should unset that session using unset($_SESSION['fname']); and then set it up again.

Comment: Thank you! I know the answer supposed to be simple. But I just started to learn PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the `$_SESSION['fname']` when you do the update. It is only set when you do the login. Because of that you will continue to echo out the data from the `$_SESSION` array until a change is made. Add something to the PHP script that does the database update to update the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: *Hm...*. Based on OP's [**other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25330469/) earlier today, am wondering "why" update's not working all of a sudden. Omission of `session_start();` also / in addition to (and in all pages using sessions)? Can't beat "full code" ;)

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Yes, I need to reset the session. The answer accepted is working good.